# What are the precise requirements for "The Day After" garbage collection mission?

Tags: simcity-2013

What are the precise requirements for "The Day After" garbage collection mission? The in-game information says that 250 cans of trash must be collected in a 24-hour period.

I recently failed the mission despite collecting, according to the garbage adviser, over 2,800 cans of garbage.

Is there a known discrepancy between how the mission counts and the garbage adviser counts? Is there some trick to the mission?

**Update**
Based on my repeated attempts, it may be that the mission only counts residential garbage. Also, it may be that the mission is really counting the number of residences, not cans.

Comment: There may be a timing thing, where picking up the quest between 6 AM and 8 AM will make it more difficult to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [common bug](https://answers.ea.com/t5/SimCity-2013/The-Day-After-garbage-collecting-challenge/td-p/841060). From what I can research, the solution would be to:

- Pick up garbage cans from residential zones like you attempted
- Hire an additional garbage truck so you can collect an *[additional](https://answers.ea.com/t5/SimCity-2013/Bug-The-Day-After-challenge/td-p/726098)* 250 garbage bins.
- This bug is 6 years old, it is also possible this it has been patched over in recent updates.

Ultimately, there is not a lot of information on this issue but these seem to be two solutions that have either worked for yourself or other people.

Comment: Interesting observation: This answer was written one day short from it being exactly 6 years after the post was made.